# Cephadm + Openstack Keystone Integration

Tags: openstack, ceph, object-storage

Hello I am trying to Integrate Openstack Keystone as Ceph authentication Mechanism So i can use ceph object storage as openstack swift backend

Environment:

```
Kernel : Ubunutu Server LTS 22.04 (minimal)
Openstack : Zed (Manual Installation)
Ceph : quiny (Cephadm Installation)
```

//Controller node

```
openstack service create --name swift object-store 

openstack user create --domain default --password-prompt swift
openstack user create --domain default --password-prompt rgw
openstack role add --user swift --project service admin
openstack role add --user swift --project service swiftoperator
openstack role add --user rgw --project service admin
openstack role add --user rgw --project service swiftoperator

openstack endpoint create --region Tehran object-store public http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1
openstack endpoint create --region Tehran object-store internal http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1
openstack endpoint create --region Tehran object-store admin http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1
```

//Ceph Cluster

```
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_api_version 3
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_url http://<keystone_url>:5000
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_accepted_roles admin,member,swiftoperator,Member,_member_
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_token_cache_size 500
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_admin_user rgw
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_admin_password rgw
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_admin_domain default
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_keystone_admin_project service
ceph config set client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh rgw_s3_auth_use_keystone true
```

Now when i run `swift list` i get this error ;(

```
Account GET failed: http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1?format=json 401 Unauthorized  [first 60 chars of response] b'{"Code":"AccessDenied","RequestId":"tx00000ff92593343f6fbac-'
Failed Transaction ID: tx00000ff92593343f6fbac-0063b3dcd8-455e0-default
```

i feel like i am missing something here i read a lot of documents only one of them found the solution and that was creating radosgw user on openstack and assigning swift operator role to it i did it the problem still exist by the way even though swift user has admin role in service project i assigned swift operator role to it! i still have the problem

```
curl -v http://<keystone_url>:5000 (on ceph-2 returns no error)
```

here is the complete `swift list --debug`

```
DEBUG:keystoneclient.auth.identity.v3.base:Making authentication request to http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/auth/tokens
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): <keystone_url>:5000
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://<keystone_url>:5000 "POST /v3/auth/tokens HTTP/1.1" 201 4678
DEBUG:keystoneclient.auth.identity.v3.base:{"token": {"methods": ["password"], "user": {"domain": {"id": "default", "name": "Default"}, "id": "6622244113204a689e3a367847291166", "name": "hoodad", "password_expires_at": null}, "audit_ids": ["zNYqN-lESbCt8U1MA3tl5Q"], "expires_at": "2023-01-03T08:41:55.000000Z", "issued_at": "2023-01-03T07:41:55.000000Z", "project": {"domain": {"id": "default", "name": "Default"}, "id": "36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "name": "admin"}, "is_domain": false, "roles": [{"id": "5365f6dcb2fc4577a3c31693e671e5ee", "name": "reader"}, {"id": "7d90492c8771403b93d5bf8e1d33e40b", "name": "admin"}, {"id": "514cde82919e436aaec7568ad1ba4bee", "name": "member"}], "catalog": [{"endpoints": [{"id": "349bda8b61cc4bee932887f213de41c7", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8776/v3/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "8c981d7f64f74174ba1a0bc3eaf4aa91", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8776/v3/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "9c94c3bdc0394abea5f3646f8986022f", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8776/v3/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "061f492117d74190bc0084986feb377a", "type": "volumev3", "name": "cinder"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "3fd3b010a41b4a3a86fa76b308f3a053", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "455c040c8f304f4e99eae8104a57ec17", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "86e24eb7164d449da0a8bf56af1d56b7", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "1c97054f81db4fcc8ed16d3aa42869a9", "type": "identity", "name": "keystone"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "16be2834ab4d4fdb9c4c293b550d4980", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8778", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "b58356f6e25747a7bce5e9c9c4a0bd7e", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8778", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "cd7430601c6d4e928e3ea279aa75d63d", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8778", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "6408ac009be64d93b82c6803aad17607", "type": "placement", "name": "placement"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "a21330d45c8f4530a06c99a62c187e14", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9696", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "dbc4d63dfbb94ae7afcf20458b428319", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9696", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "de26e420bc994cb9b9332922f088a670", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9696", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "694e0790a22d41c29585b786bc263009", "type": "network", "name": "neutron"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "85434ec1ef2e4d2ca52f0467df6a9001", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9292", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "98773c3f67b640f18f53885b569e4d73", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9292", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "c1e80464da124b7eaa0279e28c1f25d2", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9292", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "c8fe90a32cfc417fa5369b60092c0dfc", "type": "image", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "26464c37332e4c0da96ca4e8f7b82ae9", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8774/v2.1/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "623dc6a74b634117b3edcc5892cc1bbb", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8774/v2.1/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "8314196253d2446aaeec6e9e6e45fd47", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8774/v2.1/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "ccc120553ee14e3f8b3157f698190492", "type": "compute", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "8751532bb2ca4f81a0f51ecb67df6eb4", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "9f31cf8882554f199ab9ead345e05825", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "e98011666e844f13aac4e423a316fde6", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "e38f897497d547c6a06bb6a52be1be13", "type": "object-store", "name": "swift"}]}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): <rados_gatway>:8080
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://<rados_gatway>:8080 "GET /swift/v1?format=json HTTP/1.1" 401 119
INFO:swiftclient:REQ: curl -i http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1?format=json -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABjs9xDrD6NgcD6Uyatc0QH4q74_SiztiLkYPpoHKK0b8yGWwyXfAw-V4klq7x6nCekqmHwa2ELQVHI_Cj5AzygU98Hdr6rrrpL3Wihl1CdqMyoXnw_GdNWh4dNQPGxOQatYXR2XwU5U7r9Juv-G4cJjFYFh5RRKyPNCzN6z_vhI-xm5sc" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
INFO:swiftclient:RESP STATUS: 401 Unauthorized
INFO:swiftclient:RESP HEADERS: {'Content-Length': '119', 'X-Trans-Id': 'tx00000a7c6f54a4f0a7eac-0063b3dc43-455e0-default', 'X-Openstack-Request-Id': 'tx00000a7c6f54a4f0a7eac-0063b3dc43-455e0-default', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Date': 'Tue, 03 Jan 2023 07:41:55 GMT', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'}
INFO:swiftclient:RESP BODY: b'{"Code":"AccessDenied","RequestId":"tx00000a7c6f54a4f0a7eac-0063b3dc43-455e0-default","HostId":"455e0-default-default"}'
DEBUG:keystoneclient.auth.identity.v3.base:Making authentication request to http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/auth/tokens
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): <keystone_url>:5000
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://<keystone_url>:5000 "POST /v3/auth/tokens HTTP/1.1" 201 4678
DEBUG:keystoneclient.auth.identity.v3.base:{"token": {"methods": ["password"], "user": {"domain": {"id": "default", "name": "Default"}, "id": "6622244113204a689e3a367847291166", "name": "hoodad", "password_expires_at": null}, "audit_ids": ["B3g606MNTUqZS6tUgEHyHQ"], "expires_at": "2023-01-03T08:41:56.000000Z", "issued_at": "2023-01-03T07:41:56.000000Z", "project": {"domain": {"id": "default", "name": "Default"}, "id": "36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "name": "admin"}, "is_domain": false, "roles": [{"id": "5365f6dcb2fc4577a3c31693e671e5ee", "name": "reader"}, {"id": "7d90492c8771403b93d5bf8e1d33e40b", "name": "admin"}, {"id": "514cde82919e436aaec7568ad1ba4bee", "name": "member"}], "catalog": [{"endpoints": [{"id": "349bda8b61cc4bee932887f213de41c7", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8776/v3/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "8c981d7f64f74174ba1a0bc3eaf4aa91", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8776/v3/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "9c94c3bdc0394abea5f3646f8986022f", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8776/v3/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "061f492117d74190bc0084986feb377a", "type": "volumev3", "name": "cinder"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "3fd3b010a41b4a3a86fa76b308f3a053", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "455c040c8f304f4e99eae8104a57ec17", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "86e24eb7164d449da0a8bf56af1d56b7", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:5000/v3/", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "1c97054f81db4fcc8ed16d3aa42869a9", "type": "identity", "name": "keystone"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "16be2834ab4d4fdb9c4c293b550d4980", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8778", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "b58356f6e25747a7bce5e9c9c4a0bd7e", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8778", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "cd7430601c6d4e928e3ea279aa75d63d", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8778", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "6408ac009be64d93b82c6803aad17607", "type": "placement", "name": "placement"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "a21330d45c8f4530a06c99a62c187e14", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9696", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "dbc4d63dfbb94ae7afcf20458b428319", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9696", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "de26e420bc994cb9b9332922f088a670", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9696", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "694e0790a22d41c29585b786bc263009", "type": "network", "name": "neutron"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "85434ec1ef2e4d2ca52f0467df6a9001", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9292", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "98773c3f67b640f18f53885b569e4d73", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9292", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "c1e80464da124b7eaa0279e28c1f25d2", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:9292", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "c8fe90a32cfc417fa5369b60092c0dfc", "type": "image", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "26464c37332e4c0da96ca4e8f7b82ae9", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8774/v2.1/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "623dc6a74b634117b3edcc5892cc1bbb", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8774/v2.1/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "8314196253d2446aaeec6e9e6e45fd47", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<keystone_url>:8774/v2.1/36905f5fbaa64feaa0a47dcc3d8f5455", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "ccc120553ee14e3f8b3157f698190492", "type": "compute", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"id": "8751532bb2ca4f81a0f51ecb67df6eb4", "interface": "public", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "9f31cf8882554f199ab9ead345e05825", "interface": "internal", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1", "region": "Tehran"}, {"id": "e98011666e844f13aac4e423a316fde6", "interface": "admin", "region_id": "Tehran", "url": "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1", "region": "Tehran"}], "id": "e38f897497d547c6a06bb6a52be1be13", "type": "object-store", "name": "swift"}]}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): <rados_gatway>:8080
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://<rados_gatway>:8080 "GET /swift/v1?format=json HTTP/1.1" 401 119
INFO:swiftclient:REQ: curl -i http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1?format=json -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABjs9xEgshf9a7GAexTEQ27dZFkFSP7TaC-o-2Bba_WbaH7WeMS9ohHrJhlU_tFdcWsd-71UEE4e33bOEtA8vM6yA6Nu2IAm8SU2QN6Ox5tuhps5Dc0E_inQfqxg-9cAgpjwsm8czG06SsCku6Cgxt-UqSdyCGn9CcShRgH0u7Mb1eyEvw" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
INFO:swiftclient:RESP STATUS: 401 Unauthorized
INFO:swiftclient:RESP HEADERS: {'Content-Length': '119', 'X-Trans-Id': 'tx0000081618694ce1134ad-0063b3dc44-455e0-default', 'X-Openstack-Request-Id': 'tx0000081618694ce1134ad-0063b3dc44-455e0-default', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Date': 'Tue, 03 Jan 2023 07:41:56 GMT', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'}
INFO:swiftclient:RESP BODY: b'{"Code":"AccessDenied","RequestId":"tx0000081618694ce1134ad-0063b3dc44-455e0-default","HostId":"455e0-default-default"}'
ERROR:swiftclient.service:Account GET failed: http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1?format=json 401 Unauthorized  [first 60 chars of response] b'{"Code":"AccessDenied","RequestId":"tx0000081618694ce1134ad-' (txn: tx0000081618694ce1134ad-0063b3dc44-455e0-default)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/swiftclient/service.py", line 949, in _list_account_job
    _, items = conn.get_account(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1911, in get_account
    return self._retry(None, get_account, marker=marker, limit=limit,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 1856, in _retry
    rv = func(self.url, self.token, *args,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/swiftclient/client.py", line 883, in get_account
    raise ClientException.from_response(resp, 'Account GET failed', body)
swiftclient.exceptions.ClientException: Account GET failed: http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1?format=json 401 Unauthorized  [first 60 chars of response] b'{"Code":"AccessDenied","RequestId":"tx0000081618694ce1134ad-' (txn: tx0000081618694ce1134ad-0063b3dc44-455e0-default)
Account GET failed: http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1?format=json 401 Unauthorized  [first 60 chars of response] b'{"Code":"AccessDenied","RequestId":"tx0000081618694ce1134ad-'
Failed Transaction ID: tx0000081618694ce1134ad-0063b3dc44-455e0-default
```

Answer (score 0):

[Incomplete]
I was able to make it work with Ceph Octopus (slightly modified config changes), see details below. I'm still trying to get a working Pacific RGW configuration, Quincy also currently doesn't work for me.

I see the cross project notes in the latest [docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/keystone/). It might not be a fully satisfying answer, but in order to paste my notes a comment is not sufficient. Here's what worked for me with Ceph Octopus and OpenStack Victoria:

```
# ceph.conf
[client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh]
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_keystone_api_version 3
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_keystone_accepted_roles "admin,Member,_member_,member"
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_keystone_admin_user rgw
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_keystone_admin_password ****
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_keystone_admin_domain default
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_keystone_admin_project service
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_s3_auth_use_keystone true
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_keystone_url https://control.fqdn:5000
ceph config set client.rgw.keystone.storage01.vtakeh rgw_swift_account_in_url true
---

# create swift service
$ openstack service create --name=swift --description="Swift Service" object-store
$ openstack user create rgw --password *****
# add role to user
$ openstack role add --user rgw --project service admin

# create keystone endpoints
$ openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne swift admin "http://ses6-mon1.fqdn:80/swift/v1/AUTH_$(project_id)s" 
$ openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne swift internal "http://ses6-mon1.fqdn:80/swift/v1/AUTH_$(project_id)s" 
$ openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne swift public "http://ses6-mon1.fqdn:80/swift/v1/AUTH_$(project_id)s"
```

After configuring these options I was able to run `openstack container create swift1` successfully. The above commands worked for me to setup a fresh rgw and access it via openstack:

```
control01:~ # openstack container create swift1
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+
| account | container | x-trans-id                                        |
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+
| v1      | swift1    | tx0000095214f842753ecaa-00639b24cd-606d44-default |
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+
control01:~ # openstack container list
+--------+
| Name   |
+--------+
| swift1 |
+--------+
```

With minor changes basically the same worked with ceph nautilus and openstack rocky for me.

Comment: the commands above is pretty much all i did. i tried without cross tenant access the problem still exist ;(. 
by the way i use ha proxy to load balance between my rgw nodes.
i even set endpoints directly to rgw node it didn't fix problem.
i have some questions where did you put ceph.conf file (in rgw node?) ?
is the who section (client.rgw.default) correct ?
like i said i want to use it with ha proxy so it's important to set rgw user configs on whole cluster.
i also installed swift and i have all the swift configs and service is it correct ? (i feel like you only create service and endpo

Comment: With cephadm there's no need for a ceph.conf anymore, you set the configs with `ceph config set ...` as you already did. Then you'll need to restart the rgw daemons to apply the config changes. Using HAProxy is fine, of course, the endpoint then just has to point to the address HAProxy is listening to. The client section has to be configured for each of your rgw containers. But to make it easier to set up I'd recommend to start with one daemon and scale up if it works. I didn't install swift because I want to use ceph as backend, not swift, that's why I only need the endpoint and service.

Comment: i tried setting `client.rgw.default.ceph-2.ncsnqh` for who section in `ceph config` then i changed endpoints to that machine with ha proxy disabled.  i retried this setup with ceph-3 as well the problem still exist. i think there is something wrong with who section of cephadm . shouldn't `client.rgw.default` set it for entire cluster ? . i will try to reinstall entire cloud without swift maybe it's causing probelms.

Comment: I don't use rgw too much yet, but I don't think you can set your configs globally because it's a client section (RGWs are clients to ceph) and each client requires a configuration. I might be wrong, but that's my current impression. Just one more thought, is your RGW able to contact the keystone auth_url?

Comment: how should i check that ?

Comment: `curl -v https://<keystone_url>:5000` from the rgw node. But I think the error message would be something like `unauthorized (401)` but not 404. Does the rgw log anything?

Comment: yes it's connected curl returns no errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141402/discussion-between-eblock-and-hoodad-tabibi).

Comment: i set up new cloud .i found a problem i set the wrong api "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/v1/" the correct one is "http://<rados_gatway>:8080/swift/v1" i get diffrent error ;)) i updated the question above if it's possible take a look

Comment: So now you get the 401 which I assume could be a connection issue between rgw and keystone. Did you verify that the rgw node can contact keystone after you redeployed? Also maybe try without the option `rgw_swift_account_in_url`, although I'm not sure if that makes a difference. Did you try with just the options I set, no further options like the one I just mentioned?

Comment: well curl returns no error i set `swift_account_in_url to false` . the only diffrence in our settings is `token cache size` which i removed the problem still exists i give a bit more detail about commands i run and i didn't install any packages on controller pretty much all i did
`http://185.55.227.42:8080/swift/v1?format=json (ceph-2)` returns no suck key is this okay ?

`http://185.55.227.17:5000/v3/ (keystone)`

Comment: You only post URLs. From RGW node you should be able to curl keystone, so something like this:`rgw:~ # curl https://control.fqdn:5000
{"versions": {"values": [{"id": "v3.14", "status": "stable", "updated": [...]"media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v3+json"}]}]}}`. From control curl the rgw:`control:~ # curl http://rgw.fqdn:80
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ListAllMyBucketsResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Owner><ID>anonymous</ID><DisplayName></DisplayName></Owner><Buckets></Buckets></ListAllMyBucketsResult>`

Comment: Can you please provide the full output of the exact commands you tried? Otherwise you make it really difficult to follow and understand what you did.